# Obtaining empty arrays when searching elements by class with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to know the way to obtain the text of the `<a>` tags, been trying different methods but no success so far

I searched multiple ways to obtain the values, used document.getElementsByClassName() or document.getElementsByName()
but the arrays returned empty all the time

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Currencies</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="saveData();" />

    </br>
    <div class ="currencies">
    <a class="mypanel"></a>
    </div>
    <script>
    var text = ``
    function getData(){

        $.getJSON('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.investing.com/common/technical_summary/api.php?action=TSB_updatePairs&pairs=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,47,48,49,50,52,53,54,55&timeframe=300', 
            function(data) {
                var x=0
                for(i=0; i<60;i++){
                try{
                text = text + `Currency_id : <a name="currid">${i}</a><br>
                               Value: <a class="summaryLast">${data[i].summaryLast}</a><br>
                            Currency: <a name="summaryName">${data[i].summaryName}</a><br>
                            Trend: <a name="trend">${data[i].technicalSummary}</a><br><br>`

                }

                catch(e){

                }

                }
                $(".mypanel").html(text);

            });

    }

    getData()

    function saveData(){

        var currency_ids = []
        $('.mypanel > a.currid').each(function(i){
          currency_ids[i] = $(this).text()
        })
        console.log(JSON.stringify(currency_ids))

        var currency_values = []
        $('.mypanel > a.summaryLast').each(function(i){
          currency_values[i] = $(this).text()
        })
        console.log(JSON.stringify(currency_values))

        var currency_name = []
        $('.mypanel > a.summaryName').each(function(i){
          currency_name[i] = $(this).text()
        })
        console.log(JSON.stringify(currency_name))
        var currency_trend = []
        $('.mypanel > a.trend').each(function(i){
          currency_trend[i] = $(this).text()
        })
        console.log(JSON.stringify(currency_trend))

    }



    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The page looks like this

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTOdD.png)

and when I click the button I expected 4 arrays to return with data, instead only one of them does, that only confuses me more..

[link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB2i7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currid`, `summaryName` and `trend` are not class names but name attributes. Change your selectors to `.mypanel > a[name="your_name_value"]`:

```js
var text = "";

function getData() {
  $.getJSON('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.investing.com/common/technical_summary/api.php?action=TSB_updatePairs&pairs=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,47,48,49,50,52,53,54,55&timeframe=300',
    function(data) {
      var x = 0
      for (i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        try {
          text = text + `Currency_id : <a name="currid">${i}</a><br>
                               Value: <a class="summaryLast">${data[i].summaryLast}</a><br>
                            Currency: <a name="summaryName">${data[i].summaryName}</a><br>
                            Trend: <a name="trend">${data[i].technicalSummary}</a><br><br>`
        } catch (e) {}
      }
      $(".mypanel").html(text);
    });
}

getData()

function saveData() {

  var currency_ids = []
  $('.mypanel > a[name="currid"]').each(function(i) {
    currency_ids[i] = $(this).text()
  })
  console.log(JSON.stringify(currency_ids))

  var currency_values = []
  $('.mypanel > a.summaryLast').each(function(i) {
    currency_values[i] = $(this).text()
  })
  console.log(JSON.stringify(currency_values))

  var currency_name = []
  $('.mypanel > a[name="summaryName"]').each(function(i) {
    currency_name[i] = $(this).text()
  })
  console.log(JSON.stringify(currency_name))
  var currency_trend = []
  $('.mypanel > a[name="trend"]').each(function(i) {
    currency_trend[i] = $(this).text()
  })
  console.log(JSON.stringify(currency_trend))

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="saveData();" />

</br>
<div class="currencies">
  <a class="mypanel"></a>
</div>
```